# Where can I find an opening database of professional games for 9x9 Go?

Tags: go, openings

I'm looking for an opening database (also called game explorer) for 9x9 Go, showing in every position the percentage of times each move is played and also possibly the percentage of times each move leads to a win for Black.

The database must only include games played by professionals.

Just like the following database, but for 9x9 instead of 19x19: http://ps.waltheri.net/

It doesn't matter if there are not a lot of games in the database. Even a hundred games would be sufficient.

---

**Edit:**
I found one! Here it is: https://online-go.com/puzzle/181
But I would still be interested in other databases. So if somebody else finds another 9x9 database, with at least as much games (361) as the previous one, please do give me its link.

Comment: If you find the answer to your own question after posting, post it as an answer. 
If you are not satisfied by the solution you found yourself, explain why you are not satisfied.

Comment: Note that the [alleged duplicate](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/48719/where-can-i-find-a-database-for-9x9-go-with-times) asks for more, namely the time spent on each move. None of the three links given in this Q&A appear to include this feature.

Answer (score 2):

It's not professional games but they are between very strong players:
http://dcook.org/compgo/9by9_experiments.html

This has tons of games:
http://gobase.org/9x9/

Comment: I have already went to both of these two pages. For the first I can't even manage to open the .tgz and .zip files... For the second page it's not what I am looking for (as I said what I'm looking for is something that shows "in every position the percentage of times each move is played and also possibly the percentage of times each move leads to a win for Black").

Comment: @user50746 : for the analysis part, several Go program will do that for you when you upload the games in their database. So just go for the databases, like the ones Liam gave you, and the one you found too