# Where can I find a database of Go games with move times

Tags: go

I am looking for a database of 19x19 Go games (complete games) including the time spent on each move, or the global time in each move. Other aspect is that its need to be without bots or any artificial intelligence, just people Vs people.

I have found databases (such as [gokifu](http://gokifu.com/)) with everything I want except for the time per move.

Comment: I thought I remembered a duplicate of this question, but I cannot find it (any more) – could one have been deleted?

Comment: I agree that this could be interesting, and one gathers from numerous studies of games (case in point: [The Meijins Retirement Game](https://senseis.xmp.net/?TheMeijinsRetirementGame) that they are recorded for professional games, but I think that the main problem with this will be that as far as I am aware the [SGF](https://senseis.xmp.net/?SGF) format does not provide for it, at least not in the standard form.

Comment: SGFv4 allows time remaining (after the move was played).  "BL" is "Black time left" and "WL" is "White time left", in seconds.  (Couldn't use BR and WR, because those were already used for players' ranks/ratings.)  "OB" and "OW" are for byo-yomi / overtime.  See https://www.red-bean.com/sgf/properties.html#WT (scroll down a couple lines).  You can also see these in the SGFs from Go servers, if you view with a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

An earlier [question about database for 9x9 games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/22759/where-can-i-find-an-opening-database-of-professional-games-for-9x9-go) contains a link to a database for 19x19 games:

http://ps.waltheri.net/